# Form 1 submit tells form 2 which inputs are selected

Tags: php, forms, post, checkbox

I want to specify, on clicking a submit button in the first form, which checkboxes and radios should be selected in form 2.

(These inputs do not exist in form 1, but I want to tell them what to do in form 2.)

The action is already set on form 1 to go to form 2, but how do I pass the information that certain checkboxes and radios should be highlighted on this new form? Where do I put that? Can I use GET or POST?

EDIT
On page 1 I have this form:

```
Choose a package (you can edit on the next page):
Package 1 CHOOSE
Package 2 CHOOSE
Package 3 CHOOSE
```

The user will select one of those, and the next page will show up with an options form. For example, if user selects Package 3:

```
(O)Option 1(Incl. in Package 3)
()Option 2
()Option 3

[] Addition 1
[x] Addition 2(Incl. in Package 3)
[x] Addition 3(Incl. in Package 3)
[] Addition 4
```

Since option 1 and Additions 2 and 3 are included in the previously selected Package 3, I want them to be selected on the new page. This is what I need to learn how to do. Should I be using jQuery or PHP? And how do I reference these values to check the inputs?

EDIT 2

Now I am trying to tie the event to the submit button on the first form. I am using Get so that the url will read "blahblah.com?page=this&choice=12&choice2=other" when it works correctly. I know this part of using Get. What else do I need to do? Like I said before, these variables don't exist in the first form, so there's nothing I can capture. So how can I tell the submit button what values to load on the new page? I have tried putting in the URL plus all the variables but that doesn't work. I'm obviously missing something somewhere. Can anyone tell me what else I need to do?

Help!!!

Comment: Is the new form on a new page?

Comment: It's like this: On page 1 I have:

Comment: What determines which checkboxes and radio buttons are selected? Does anything in form1 determine that? The method you use to submit is irrelevant as both will pass the form data.

Comment: Yes, the option chosen in form 1 should tell form 2 which to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like to want to do a package of some sort, and from your description nothing major happens when you hit the server for the second form. With that in mind, a small amount of javascript ( with jQuery ) can do that job.
http://jsfiddle.net/dLSjk/

Answer (score 2):

If you have limited checkboxes and radio buttons and you don't have any privacy about the elements values, you could use GET, but if controls are more or data being transfered is secured or private then you should use POST or REQUEST....
and then use GET,POST or REQUEST to get value on next form using some scripting language..and set the form 2 controls value according to that....

Comment: Thanks, I do know that much, but I need more specific help than that.

Answer (score 1):

The decision about which elements should be available in form2 is something that PHP should be working out and then returning the correct version of form2,

```
#pseudocode
if (something was checked){
display_form2A();

}else{
display_form2B();

}
```